# Interrupt or cancel a long computation in DLL

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll, cancellation

I'm developing an SDK as a dynamic library (DLL/so). The user can set a lot of parameters prior to run the computation. But I would like to offer a way to dynamically change the parameters, which should stop the current computation and relaunch it with the new parameters. So a general usage should looks like:

```
Client Caller thread -----> Call my SDK -----> Computation code
                                                      ^
                                                      |
                                                      |
Client UI Thread ----> Request cancelation ------------
```

I have a lot of questions about the mechanics and I'm wondering what are the good practices to do so.

1) How to handle the interrupt ?

- Should I run my computation in an async thread, and just drop the results of that thread?
- Should I use a `std::atomic<bool>` that the computation thread checks sometime to return to start point?

2) If using the second options, what is the best way to return to the launch point?

- Is it okay to use C++ exceptions that case? (NOTE: I already use exception for really rare case in the computation code.)
- Should it have Error code handling all along with early checks to avoid computing?
- Could `longjmp` or something similar that can be used?

Answer (score 1):

For proper object cleanup and resource reclamation, you need to either throw an exception or just stop the calculation and let the calculation functions return normally.

You should not abort the thread or use `longjmp`, as they will not destroy the objects your calculation has created, leading to leaks of memory and whatever other resources (like file handles) you may be using.

Using a `std::atomic` (that is easily accessible from everywhere) that your calculations poll periodically is one way to achieve this.  You'll need to check this regularly, so the check will need to be in or near any loops you have.  Short, quick loops don't need to check while they are looping, but there should be some sort of check at least several times a second.  Once you detect the cancellation request, you can either throw your exception, or return from the current function (so the parent function would also need to check for cancellation).

One downside to all that is if you miss a check in a loop someplace, your cancellation may not happen right away.